# vuejs select default option does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a json data that i've been loading into the `<select>`

This is a sample json data that I have:

```
let plans = [{id: 20, name: "test", default: 0},
{id: 19, name: "haha", default: 0},
{id: 18, name: "okok", default: 1}];
```

This is my select html/vue.

```
<select id="plans" class="form-control" v-model="company.plan_id">
    <option v-for="plan in plans" :value="plan.id" :selected="plan.default">{{plan.name}}</option>
</select>
```

It seems it doesn't select the "okok" value even if the `default` is `1`.

Those `plans` data are coming from my database which is loaded using ajax.

I'm new to VueJS, any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`selected` attribute no longer makes sense when you using `v-model`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `selected` attribute if you are using `v-model` on the `<select>`, Set the `v-model` value to the default value instead:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <select id="plans" class="form-control" v-model="company.plan_id">
      <option v-for="plan in plans" :value="plan.id" :key="plan.id" :selected="plan.default">{{plan.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      company: {
        plan_id: 18
      },
      plans: [
        { id: 20, name: "test" },
        { id: 19, name: "haha" },
        { id: 18, name: "okok" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sound-gxmzu?file=/src/App.vue